# Cannot get Ajax variable in Node JS

Tags: html, css, node.js, sql-server, ajax

I create a AJAX as below:

```
<script>
    $("button[type='submit']").click(function (){
       
        var length = $('.service__title').length;
        var title = [];
        var quantity = [];
        var subtotal = [];

        for(let i = 0; i < length; i++){

                title.push($('.service__title').eq(i).text());
                quantity.push(parseInt($('.display__number').eq(i).text()));
                subtotal.push(parseInt($('.display__total').eq(i).text()));

        }
        $.ajax({
            url: "../booking/success",
            type: "POST",
            data: {title:title, quantity:quantity, subtotal:subtotal}
            // contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
          });
    });

</script>
```

When I console log req.body at terminal, I got:

```
{
  title: [
    '1 x Private Self Makeup Class',
    'Bridesmaid Look + Hair/Hijab do (no retouch)'
  ],
  quantity: [ '6', '3' ],
  subtotal: [ '4200000', '900000' ]
}
{
  Dkhang: 'Viasss',
  DPhone: '0943064201',
  DEmail: 'q12@gmail.com',
  DDate: '2020-09-16',
  DTime: '00:00',
  DAdress: 'Holo',
  DTinh: '11',
  DQuan: '11',
  service: '32',
  DComment: ''
}
```

Pls kindly guide me how to use Ajax in my index.js at server. I cannot run

```
app.post("/", function(req,res){
    let x = req.body.title.join(", ");
    sql_text="SELECT * FROM Service WHERE Title IN ("+ x +")";
    db.query(sql_text, (err, rows)=>{
        if(err) res.send(err)
        else{
            res.render("services")
        }
    })
})
```

When I console log req.body.title, i get 2 object: title and undefined object
Please help me!!!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what do you mean you got object title when you console log the req.body.title.

But you are requesting

```
SELECT * FROM Service WHERE Title IN (1 x Private Self Makeup Class, Bridesmaid Look + Hair/Hijab do (no retouch))
```

which should be

```
SELECT * FROM Service WHERE Title IN ("1 x Private Self Makeup Class", "Bridesmaid Look + Hair/Hijab do (no retouch)")
```

and query SQL by string concat is dangerous for being [SQL injection](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp).
Check out [W3School](https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_mysql_where.asp) and see how to escape query values by using the placeholder `?`

Or personally I suggest you to use [knex](https://www.npmjs.com/package/knex) or [sequelize](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sequelize) instead.